# How to declare a UIImage Object in the Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let hopAnimation:[UIImage] = UIImage(named:"background")
```

I do this but Xcode tells me:

```
Expected ',' separator Fix-it insert ','
```

Comment: `[UIImage]` is an *array* of images. Just `let hopAnimation = ...`

Comment: `let hopAnimation = UIImage(named:"background")` Try this code.

Comment: var image = UIImage(named:"ImageName")

Comment: let hopAnimation = UIImage(named:"background") is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code.It showed me the `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to specified type '[UIImage]'`. Then I removed the [UIImage]

```
let hopAnimation = UIImage(named:"background")
```

Now it does not show the error

I must tell that

```
[UIImage] is an array of images.Here you are not creating array of image.You create only image.So remove the array of images.
```

Comment: Thank you.Why the Auto-Complete of the name of Image files will lead the fault,When i code every word by myself it is ok?

Comment: Can you ask me clearly?

Comment: sorry,my english is very poor.                                                                          
 i mean,the third UIImage is auto-complete                                                                                                        let hopAnimation:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named:"frame-1")!,
                                      UIImage(named:"frame-2")!,
                                      UIImage(named:"#imageLiteral(resourceName: "frame-2")")!
        ]

Comment: You can't code yourself.You need to follow codes from Apple,Tutorial,SO,Programming site according to your requirement.If you want to make image picker or set image for button... follow the authorized codes.

Comment: No No you should not write like that.

Comment: Is my answer helpful for you?

Comment: can i add your facebook?I wanna show you the pic of my question code,it beset me hours.

Comment: yeah,i  have correct it ,it's helpful

Comment: I don't have accounts in Facebook.Is it any another way to show me?

Answer (score 1):

`[UIImage]` declares an array of images. To create a single image, use:

`var hopAnimation = UIImage(named:"background")`